# VSCode "Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'UNIX[No such file or directory]'."

Tags: macos, authentication, visual-studio-code, sync-settings

**After solving this and posting to AskDifferent.... I realized this is probably the case with any OS:**

in my case I was using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with new install of VSCode 1.50.0 (see screenshots below):

### Scenario:

- Attempt to "Sign-in to Sync Settings"

  [image]
- web/browser-based SSO redirects to Microsoft and/or Github browser login
- login fails - error message in VSCode:

### Error:

> `Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'UNIX[No such file or directory]'.`

### System Details:

- New install of VSCode For Mac:
  [image]
- And MacOS info:
  [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a keychain error which look similar to some others upon Google search, but I didn't find this exact error... so, adding the solution here...

**SOLUTION**

1. Attempt to "Sync Settings" by logging into Microsoft or Github
2. this will fail as OP states... but
3. close ALL instances/windows of VSCode
4. RESTART VSCode
5. You should be prompted for Apple KeyChain permissions like this image shows:
   [image]
6. Type in your MacOS `root` password
7. You will either immediately login without error(s) ... or....
8. RESTART VSCode AGAIN
9. "Sync Settings" / login once more

Answer (score 14):

On my system all I had to do is :

```sh
$ sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

So I think on MacOs you can also easily solve this issue by installing a keyring system. I don't know MacOs though so I couldn't provide a name.

Comment: ps: macOS users down-vote my answer I guess. Sure I don't provide a straight and concrete answer to the question but still I lead on the path of finding one, because one wouldn't know what a keyring system is, and by providing this information they could search and find themselves how to troubleshoot their own issue. I don't care getting downvotes, what trouble me is that people downvote for no valid reasons, and all I did was trying to help, and give my time. Really deceiving.

Comment: It's useful as general advice for people looking for the same error. But I, for one, arrived here looking for a macOS solution... I understand who would give a -1 though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. This worked for me on Raspberry Pi 4 with Manjaro Linux and Mate desktop. Though the error message said the org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any keyring.